# Xcode "arpa/telnet.h" file not found

Tags: ios, c, linux, xcode, macos

I am building NC app with Xcode 7.2. I am downloaded NC source code from http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/netcat/netcat-30.20.1/

when I try to run it I get :

> 'arpa/telnet.h' file not found

Why is this error occurring and how do I go about solving it?

Comment: does your file system include `/usr/`?  does it include `/usr/arpa/`?  does it include `/usr/arpa/telnet.h`?  If all that is 'true' then the xcode is not setup correctly.  (caveat: I'n not familiar with `xcode`)  can you compile and link C program, like `helloWorld.c`?   Have you downloaded+installed all the header and library files?  Have you told `xcode` where those header and library files are located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some header file are not included in os x and you must download them from :https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc

and import them manually to project.

for example "arpa/telnet.h" is here :

https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-339/include/arpa/telnet.h

Comment: That isn't true; I have `arpa/telnet.h` within the Xcode app bundle.  Go to terminal and `find /Applications/Xcode.app -name telnet.h` to see for yourself.  Looks to me like here's an issue with your Xcode set-up.

Comment: Look at question tags , its ios . When you build an ios project and include <arpa/telnet.h> in mac os 10.11 and xcode 7.2 you will get an error

Comment: Look at the result of the command in my comment; you'll see they exist in both the iOS and tvOS SDKs.  **EDIT** Actually they don't; they only exist in the simulator SDKs, not the device SDKs.  Undoing my downvote with an edit. However the question is also tagged `osx`, so your answer isn't universal to your question.

Comment: I test this when i include arpa/telnet .h in main.c xcode sys file not found . As i know telnet.h file must be in /usr/local/include

Comment: Well it depends what platform you are compiling for.  For OSX, it's included.